# How to put a button to action in an email template in RoR

Tags: ruby-on-rails

My application sends notification emails to users, I would like to put a button in the email that links to a certain action in a controller?

When I put regular html code (like `<input type="button" .... />`, I get it in the received email as string, that is, I find the html code in the email) How can I skip this trap?

Answer (score 1):

It's not a perfect idea to send messages as `html`. By default I turn off html in my email account.

Look this screencast for a beginning: http://railscasts.com/episodes/206-action-mailer-in-rails-3. You just need to specify different view formats: `html` or `text` for plain text. But in any case it will rely on reciever email settings which format will be choosen.

Comment: thanks, i've learned that you cannot include a button or a form inside an email, it's dangerous, so, i'm trying some links and images

Comment: @EbnLoQman, if the answer is helpful, upvote it and/or accept it. The only way you'll get fast answers to your future questions is displaying willingness to reward your answerer with points.